# Password Validation Else Statement Firing When It Shouldn't

Tags: c, if-statement, for-else

I am trying to validate a password in C, and one of my `else` statements is firing automatically whenever the code runs.  I run a test to see if a character is a symbol, and if it is add 1 to `int symbol` using `symbol++;`, but the problem is that this code is executing regardless of whether the character I am testing is a symbol.

I think this issue has something to do with the structure of my `if, else` statements, and I have tried several combinations, but something is wrong that is throwing the program off  I've used `else if` but that didn't help.  This seems like it should be really obvious, but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

```
char password[30];
int lower, upper, number, symbol, i;
lower = upper = number = symbol = 0;

printf("Enter your password: ");
scanf("%s", &password);

int len = strlen(password);

for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {

    if (isalpha(password[i])){

        if (isupper(password[i])){
            upper++;
        }

        else{
            lower++;
        }
    }

    if (isdigit(password[i])){
        number++;
    }

    else{
        symbol++;
    }
}

if (upper >= 1 && lower >= 1 && number >= 1 && symbol >= 1 && len >=6){

    printf("Your password is good!");

}

if (upper < 1){

    printf("You need an uppercase letter \n");

}

if (lower < 1){

    printf("You need a lowercase letter \n");

}

if (number < 1){

    printf("You need a number \n");

}

if (symbol < 1){

    printf("You need a symbol \n");

}

if (len < 6){

    printf("Your password must be at least 6 characters \n");

}
```

Comment: `symbol++;` will execute when an alpha is entered. To prevent this, insert `else` before the `isdigit` test. `else if (isdigit(password[i]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, change

```
for (i = 0; i <= len; i++)
```

to

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
```

as, `C` arrays have `0` based index. Otherwise, you *may be* overrunning allocated memory which in turn invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Note: Even if you don't overrun memory (as you have a compile time allocated array and the input *maybe* less than the actual array size), you'll end up comparing the terminating `nul`, which probably you don't want.

Then , the `isdigit()` check should not a *standalone* `if` (as per your logic), it should be an `else if` with `isalpha()`.

That said,

```
 scanf("%s", &password);
```

should be

```
 scanf("%29s", &password);
```

to avoid any possible risk of buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
symbol++;
```

will execute when an alpha is entered.

To prevent this, insert `else` before the `isdigit` test.

```
else if (isdigit(password[i])) {
```

Also the loop is incorrect as others point out. It should be

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You have code that looks like this:

```
if (cond1){}
if (cond2){}
else {}
```

In this case, execution of the `else`-block is independent of the `cond1`-block, as stated by the C11 draft standard, Section 6.8.4.1 $3: `An else is associated with the lexically nearest preceding if that is allowed by the syntax.`

You can change the structure of the code to:

```
if (cond1){}
else if (cond2){}
else {}
```